# Connecting Arduino with Ip Camera

Tags: arduino, webserver, arduino-uno, ip-camera, arduino-ide

```
/*


 Arduino with Ethernet Shield
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <Servo.h> 
int led = 4;
Servo microservo; 
int pos = 0; 
byte mac[ ] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };   //physical mac address
byte ip[ ] = { 10, 0,1,6 };                      // ip in lan (that's what you need to use in your browser. ("10.0.1.2")
byte gateway[ ] = { 10,0, 1, 25 };                   // internet access via router
byte subnet[ ] = { 255, 255, 255, 0 };                  //subnet mask
EthernetServer server(80);                             //server port     
String readString;

void setup() {
 // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  microservo.attach(7);
  // start the Ethernet connection and the server:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);
  server.begin();
  Serial.print("server is at ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}


void loop() {
  // Create a client connection
  EthernetClient client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    while (client.connected()) {   
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();

        //read char by char HTTP request
        if (readString.length() < 100) {
          //store characters to string
          readString += c;
          //Serial.print(c);
         }

         //if HTTP request has ended
         if (c == '\n') {          
           Serial.println(readString); //print to serial monitor for debuging


           client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK"); //send new page
           client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
           client.println();     
           client.println("<HTML>");
           client.println("<HEAD>");
           client.println("<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes' />");
           client.println("<meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style' content='black-translucent' />");
           client.println("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://10.0.1.2/top.htm' />");
           client.println("<TITLE>Arduino Home Security System</TITLE>");
           client.println("</HEAD>");
           client.println("<BODY>");
           client.println("<H1>Abel & Herwandi</H1>");
           client.println("<hr />");
           client.println("<br />");  
           client.println("<H2>Arduino with Ethernet Shield</H2>");
           client.println("<br />");  
           client.println("<a href=\"/?button1on\"\">Turn On LED</a>");
           client.println("<a href=\"/?button1off\"\">Turn Off LED</a><br />");   
           client.println("<br />");     
           client.println("<br />"); 
           client.println("<a href=\"/?button2on\"\">Rotate Left</a>");
           client.println("<a href=\"/?button2off\"\">Rotate Right</a><br />"); 
           client.println("<p>Designed by Abel & Herwandi. SCUT Class 5</p>");  
           client.println("<br />"); 
           client.println("</BODY>");
           client.println("</HTML>");

           delay(1);
           //stopping client
           client.stop();
           //controls the Arduino if you press the buttons
           if (readString.indexOf("?button1on") >0){
               digitalWrite(led, HIGH);

           }
           if (readString.indexOf("?button1off") >0){
               digitalWrite(led, LOW);
           }
           if (readString.indexOf("?button2on") >0){
                for(pos = 0; pos < 180; pos += 3)  // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees 
                {                                  // in steps of 1 degree 
                  microservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
                  delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
                } 
           }
           if (readString.indexOf("?button2off") >0){
                for(pos = 180; pos>=1; pos-=3)     // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees 
                {                                
                  microservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos' 
                  delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position 
                } 
           }
            //clearing string for next read
            readString="";  

         }
       }
    }
}
}
```

I'm working on a Security System using Arduino uno board, Arduino ethernet shield and dcs-930L Ip camera, and a servo motor, i have the address t directly access video and photos directly from web browser, i used ethernet shield to setup a website so that i can control the servo it actually works, so what I would like to do is set up a button so that when clicked it give me a video/image from my ip camera it can either be inside the same Arduino website or open another window browser! I appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: If you want it in the same arduino page you can try to add an iframe pointing to the camera address; if you want to open a new browser page just google for "javascript open new page" and you'll find tons of guides

Comment: @frarugi87 appreciate your help, but still a newbie so far, so can u guide through the iframe pointing to the camera address?

Comment: in my experience, the fastest way to get help is using google. If you google for "iframe", the first result is the w3p guide. And the most basic example is this: `<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>`. just change the src parameter to the page you need.

Comment: Just one remark: I don't know if you'll be able to see it in the browser,. because sometimes the security policies prevent displaying other domains in iframes. I'm not sure if "other domains" is also two different IPs in the same local network, but if this is the case the solution can be more complicated

Comment: thanks for the help but iframe dont seem to be an arduino parameter or function so unfortunately its not working

Comment: What? Where did you write the HTML code? I suppose in a string or in a html file on the SD card. Well, the iframe should go into the string or into the file, not in the arduino code... For the arduino board, that one is just a string..

Comment: I'm using the Arduino IDE, i have the arduino code how can i send to you

Comment: Please, edit your question post and paste the relevant code.

Comment: I juts updated the question with the code that I'm using from nerdtutorials

Comment: @drexxx ok, as you can see you are sending an html page to the other browser sending one line at a time. So, maybe after the `client.println("<a href=\"/?button1off\"\">Turn Off LED</a><br />");`, you can add `client.println("<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>");`...

Comment: it actually worked just add to edit the double quote after src, like client.println("<iframe src='http://www.3schools.com'></iframe>");

Comment: thanks a lot! now half way t my goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a button to the site that opens a new window showing the IP camera feed you can use this HTML, just replace `PutUrlHere` with the URL of the camera feed:

```
<a href="PutUrlHere" target="_blank">
    <input type="button" value="Show Camera">
</a>
```

EDIT:

For your program you should be able to do this wherever you want the button to show:

```
client.println("<a href='PutUrlHere' target='_blank'><input type='button' value='Show Camera'></a>");
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I inserted the code and it works like a charm